# Qt, how to make Tooltip visible without hovering over the control?

Tags: qt, focus, hover, tooltip, visible

I want tooltips to be **visible by default** when the container widget gets **focus/visible**.

I want tooltip to appear without being mouse hover on the respective control.

Answer (score 6):

You need to subclass the widget and override handler(s) for event(s) which should produce tooltip display. In the handler, create a `QHelpEvent` of type `QEvent::ToolTip` and enqueue it at the event loop. Finally call the parent's original handler, to let it do what was originally intended.

So specifically for getting focus on button, it would be

```
class MyButton : public QPushButton {
  virtual void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *) {
    if(evt->gotFocus()) {
      QPoint pos(0,0);
      QHelpEvent* help = new QHelpEvent(
        QEvent::ToolTip,pos,this->mapToGlobal(pos));
      QCoreApplication::postEvent(this,help);
    }
    QPushButton::focusInEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

For visibility you would override

```
void QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent * event);
```

and do similar code. You need to adjust relative `pos` to your taste, because originally tooltip dependens on mouse position which you don't have here. Also keep very tight control over making your widgets focused and/or visible. By default, something gets focus all the time, so you will get tooltips all over the place.